# The strategyn of Streaming API

Tags: java, web-services, twitter

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

> An app which connects to the Streaming APIs will not be able to establish a connection in response to a user request, as shown in the above example. Instead, the code for maintaining the Streaming connection is typically run in a process separate from the process which handles HTTP requests

As it says the streaming api istead of traditional api,  there is one api used for maintain the streaming connection, how to do it?
We know the http is something stateless, and only browser make request, and server can make response, how can it maintain the connection? is that client continuely sent request, or the socket in html5, or this issue is not relevant with http, it is just something about c/s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not issue of http, it will be something run under the http, like c/s